# Login to chrome without desktop environment

Tags: linux, google-chrome, gnome

If I try to open Google Chrome without having my desktop environment running (I run it from a different user account with "`su - < user >`" or remotely via `ssh -X`), Chrome tells me my login credentials are expired. When I try to log in again it seems to get stuck.

I've found that if I log into Gnome I can use that shell to open chrome on a different display with my login credentials working, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something from the Gnome environment when I log in via ssh. I read somewhere the chrome used to use the gnome-keyring to store synced settings but I thought this is no longer the case.

Anyone know how I can get this working so I can run chrome remotely and be logged in?

Comment: I found one link, not sure if it helps , https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-chrome-remote-desktop-to-access-your-computer-anywhere--cms-21227

Comment: @HarshalBenake Thanks, but that's more about desktop sharing/vnc. I'm trying to open a chrome browser from a remote browser with a local x server which is slightly different